# ¿Cómo ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado en sql desde oracle con linkedserver?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Buenos días quisiera ejecutar un store procedure de oracle en sql server mediante linkedservers. Agradezco de antemano.

store procedure oracle

```
create or replace procedure HORAS_SIGERI
  (c1 out sys_refcursor, CODIGO_PROY VARCHAR , FECHA_INICIO_VAL DATE,FECHA_FIN_VAL DATE)
  as
  begin
  open c1 for  SELECT
        rh.id_colaborador,
        rh.nombre_colaborador,
        rh.id_unidad_organizativa,
        rh.id_proyecto,
        rh.descripcion_proyecto,
        rh.tipo_actividad,
        rh.fecha,
        rh.horas_imputadas
    FROM
        view_horas_sigeri rh
    WHERE rh.id_unidad_organizativa =CODIGO_PROY AND rh.fecha BETWEEN fecha_inicio_val AND fecha_fin_val 
    order by 1,7; 
  end;
```

He visto ejemplos de ejecutar consultas desde oracle en sql con linkserver pero no un procedimiento almacenado(Aqui un ejemplo de consulta oracle en sql) y como pasarle parametros.

SQL

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DB_SIGERI, 'SELECT * FROM JIRADBUSER.PROJECT')
```

Pero quiero ejecutar este procedimiento almacenado de SQL que contiene dentro otro procedimiento almacenado en oracle usando openquery y linkedserver pero no funciona.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_HORAS_SIGERI2
@NPROYECTO varchar(50),
@FINICIO DATE,
@FFIN DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
    @TSQL varchar(8000)
    SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(BD_SIGERI,''EXEC HORAS_SIGERI c1,''''' + @NPROYECTO + ''''','''''+@FINICIO+''''','''''+@FFIN+''''' '')'
    EXEC (@TSQL)
END
```